Replacing Objective Function in Pyomo model with Persistent Solver (APPSI)
I'm interested to know if there is a canonical example of how to replace an objective function in a pyomo LP when using any of the persistent solvers in the appsi module.
The documentation says that it is possible and also warns that the old component must be deleted before doing this to prevent dupes in the model.  But I cannot find a way to delete the orig objective function.  The "removal" functions appear to be limited to variables, constraints, and blocks.
The bigger picture...  I'm hoping to employ appsi solver on a large LP by relaxing the original objective, setting that as a constraint and pursuing alternate objectives.  I'm looking for reassurance that the code below is on the right track.  Specifically:

Is there a way to remove the objective safely if this isn't it?
Is it necessary to use the opt.set_instance() method to empower the appsi framework and when should that be done if replacing the objective?

I'm not overly concerned with the first iteration and transitioning the obj ==> constraint and such as long as it is the correct/safe way to set up the re-solve loop which will be extensive.
I am also interested to know if there is a safe way to replace the objective function outright within the re-solving process as this seems alluded to in the dox...
Code:
import time

import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.contrib import appsi

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=["a", "b"])
m.P = pyo.Param(m.S, initialize={"a": 1, "b": 2}, mutable=True)
m.x = pyo.Var(m.S)

@m.Constraint(m.S)
def limit(m, s):
    return m.x[s] >= m.P[s]

m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.sum_product(m.x))

opt = appsi.solvers.Highs()

# opt.config.load_solution=False
res = opt.solve(m)
print(f'orig obj: {pyo.value(m.obj)}')

# make constraint ~ old objective
m.new_constraint = pyo.Constraint(expr=pyo.sum_product(m.x) <= 5000)
# or should the above be done with opt.add_constraints?

# replace the objective -- Is this safe?
m.del_component(m.obj)
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=m.x['a'])

# opt.set_instance(m)  <--- should this be done? Should it be after swapping the obj to prevent collision?

tic = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    # manipulate a parameter without adding/deleting components
    m.P["a"] = i
    opt.solve(m)

toc = time.time()
print(f'elapsed: {toc-tic:0.2e}')

